# Creating and passing an array from one function to another

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is make it so I can create the array and check it in a single a single function as I call it in other functions so it'd be easier to just add `$list = GetUserList` instead of verifying the `$list` each time I plan on calling the `GetUserList` function.

https://pastebin.com/6h4MJH9n

What works:

```
function GetUserList {
    $name = Read-Host "Please enter the users name (multiple users can be separated by commas)"
    $names = $name.Split(",")
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $names.Count; $i++ ) {
        $firstn = $names[$i].Trim().Split(" ")[0]
        $lastn = $names[$i].Trim().Split(" ")[-1]
        $ulist += @([PSCustomObject]@{
            First = "$firstn";
            Last  = "$lastn"
        })
    }
    return $ulist
}

function UserList {
    do {
        $userlist = GetUserList
        $userlist | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        $again = Read-Host  "Is this correct? (y/n)"
    } until ( $again -eq "y" )
    $userlist | ForEach-Object {
        "First: $($_.First)"
        "Last: $($_.Last)"
    }
}

UserList
```

What doesn't work:

```
function GetUserList {
    do {
        $ulist = @()
        $name = Read-Host "Please enter the users name (multiple users can be separated by commas)"
        $names = $name.Split(",")
        for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $names.Count; $i++ ) {
            $firstn = $names[$i].Trim().Split(" ")[0]
            $lastn = $names[$i].Trim().Split(" ")[-1]
            $ulist += @([PSCustomObject]@{
                First = "$firstn";
                Last  = "$lastn"
            })
        }
        $ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        $again = Read-Host "Is this correct? (y/n)"
    } until ( $again -eq "y" )
    return $ulist
}

function UserList {
    $userlist = GetUserList
    $userlist | ForEach-Object {
        "First: $($_.First)"
        "Last: $($_.Last)"
    }
}

UserList
```

I don't get an errors, it's just the code that doesn't work completely skips the for loop and I have no idea why.

Comment: this line >>> `$userlist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap` <<< is in your `GetUserList` func ... but is not defined in it. that makes the display of input fail. however, the list of names IS output. ///// plus, you are defining a $Var with the same name as one of your _functions_. **_do not do that_** - it makes things confusing for no good reason.

Comment: For starters, you are using the `$userlist` inside the function `GetUserList` when in actuality, it's value is only defined in the 2nd function. `$userlist = GetUserList`

Comment: I believe you were going for `$ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap`

Comment: Yeah sorry, you all pointed out something that I copied wrong. I stripped the code down to the bare essentials but in my actual code, $userlist is $ulist but it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Solips your `Format-Table` is polluting your output stream. [*grin*] replace that line with this >>> `$ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap | Out-Host` <<<

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the correction, that was the whole cause of the problem. I had read somewhere that Powershell "pipes" the commands so I thought that's what was causing it but I didn't quite understand why, until your suggest.

Comment: @Solips - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is situated in `$ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap` since you're not either

- storing the formatted content in a variable,
- nore sending the formatted content to the PowerShell host for printing (as stated in @Lee_Daily's comment in the OP)

PowerShell will return the formatted content to the output stream. Additionally to the formatted content you're also sending the content of `$ulist` to the output stream (via the `Return $ulist` statement). Based on that `$userlist` (via `$userlist = GetUserList`)  contains the `$ulist` content PLUS the formatted `$ulist` content.

These can also be seen when debugging your code (see [Set-PsBreakPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint?view=powershell-6)):

```
[DBG]:> $userlist

First Last
----- ----
user  1
user  2
user  3


First Last
----- ----
user  1
user  2
user  3
```

As @Lee_Daily suggests change the line `$ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap` to `$ulist | Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap | Out-Host`. Piping to `Out-Host` will prevent that the output of `Format-Table` is written to the output-stream.

Further suggested reading:

- [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)
- [PowerShell streams devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)